# How to use the pointer given from MapViewOfFile when its not ending with a Null termination character?

Tags: c

I'm new to C/C++ and I need help.

So this is what I do:

```
   HANDLE OpenH = CreateFile(filePath,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
   HANDLE hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(OpenH, NULL,PAGE_READONLY,0,0,FFD.cFileName);
   char * pBuf = (char *) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,FILE_MAP_READ,0,0,0);
   if(strstr(pBuf,searchword) != 0)
```

I am mapping text files with a lot of data in them, and I have to use the pointer `pBuf` in a `strstr`, `strcmp`, `strtok`, and other functions, but the `pBuf` doesn't have a null terminating character at the end of it and it gives me access violation every time I use it in a function. So how can I use `pBuf`?

Comment: Euh, perhaps `NUL`-terminate the buffer then? Or copy over & 0-term. the copy?

Comment: Also, if this is C and not C++, the `(char *) MapViewOfFile` cast is superfluous and is considered an error. Don't cast `void *`.

Comment: If you have any idea how big the buffer is then what H2CO3 proposes seems workable. E.g. something like `char temp_buf[200] = ""; strncpy(temp_buf, pBuf, 200);`

Comment: I can't NUll terminate the buffer because I map the files with read only settings , if I map them with read_write it messes up the text file completely. And how to copy the file when every one if them has around 40 000 chars and of course strcpy uses the Null terminating char to know where to stop .. I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `strstr` is not the right function for this purpose...
You could use `memchr` to locate the first character and afterwards check, if the rest fits:

```
int chr = 'a';
//DWORD size = GetFileSize(OpenH);
unsigned length = ... // obtain length of pBuf
const void* ptr = memchr(pBuf, chr, length);
if(ptr != NULL){
....
}
```

This is a little bit tedious, but will lead to a result eventually.

EDIT:

Using the Win32 `GetFileSize`-function you can determine the current size of the file, should work with mapping, too.

Comment: I was thinking that there might be a standard or easier way to do it, but if there is no such way i will try this. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Well, in pure C, there is not much of a choice as you are mostly dealing with raw memory. And the stdlib often relies on you to tell it how long a buffer is...

Comment: Ok do you have any suggestions how can I obtain the length of 'pBuf', a method that doesn't use Null-terminating character?

Comment: Using `GetFileSize` you should be able to determine the length of the buffer; experiment a little if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you need to know how big the file is, information that is readily available. And then you need to use a search function that does not rely on the buffer being null-terminated. If your library does not have such a function then I guess you will need to write your own.